# Is there any way to track SSH traffic (bandwidth usage) per user basis?

Tags: centos, ssh

I can track http traffic usage by parsing apache logs but is there any way to track ssh traffic usage per uses basis?

Comment: May I ask what is the benefit of this? Usually, SSH traffic is not huge unless you are copying large files over SSH.

Comment: @Khaled: Things like nervously often run rsync over ssh can quickly consume lots of bandwidth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use iptables owner module (perhaps together with other quota/reporting modules).

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m owner --uid someuser -j ACCEPT
```

And then see the output from `iptables -vL` to see the amount of packets/bytes passed through this rule, or parse the iptables statistics with some analyzer.

Answer (score 0):

None, there is no way to track SSH bandwidth usage per user, not on the server, and not externally.

Comment: thank you for your answer @Sirch. how control panels like cpanel measure the ssh traffic usage?

Comment: Do what Janne said, pipe it through something else that monitors the process by port and owner.